# Pointer to 'this' in an async method without using `fixed` or `GCHandle`

Tags: c#, async-await, this

Without thinking too hard about *why* you'd want to do this (assume crimes, if you like), I'd like to do something like this:

```cs
struct Example
{
    // imagine there are members here

    public async Task DoThingAsync()
    {
        IntPtr p;
        unsafe
        {
            Example* ptr = &this; // fails, complaining about unfixed expressions
            p = new IntPtr(ptr);
        }

        // I'd like p to still be valid here
        await Something.ElseAsync(p);
    }
}
```

Is there some way to do this? I know you can do it with locals (which are implicitly fixed, even in async methods), but `this` isn't a local. I know you can get this address of `this` inside a `fixed` statement, but it isn't possible to call `await` inside an `unsafe` block, so the flow of control will have exited the `fixed` block by the time we get to the async call and so the pointer could be dangling by then and everything will go sideways.

If we decide to make do with never modifying the struct instance via the pointer, then you can do `GCHandle.Alloc(this)` and then use `AddrOfPinnedObject()`, but that creates a boxed copy of the struct (which I'd like to avoid), and none of the other tricks I know for getting pointers to value types work on a `this` reference, and async methods can't take `in` or `ref` parameters so I can't work around it that way either... passing the struct instance in by value just results in a copy so it isn't any better than `GCHandle`.

I'm assuming the answer is "*you can't do this, and you shouldn't even want to do this*", but in case anyone knows better: can you get a pointer to `this` in an `async` method, without using `fixed` or `GCHandle`? Or must I always assume that `this` could point to a totally different place across an `await` and outside of `GCHandle` or allocation on the unnmanaged heap, there's no way to pin it in place?

(I'm currently using dotnet 6/C#10, if that matters, but I'm happy for solutions and workarounds that require later versions)

Comment: If you elide async in `public Task DoThingAsync() { }`, you can probably safely write `fixed (Example* ptr = &this) { return Something.ElseAsync((nint)ptr); }`. Of course you also have to elide async from `Something.ElseAsync()`; I don't know if that's possible. Anyway, you can then `await DoThingAsync()` somewhere else -- Not sure why you would do this, though

Comment: To clarify: assume in `Example` you have a non-public int Field named, e.g., `aField`, in `Something.ElseAsync()` you can write something like `unsafe { return Task.FromResult(((Example*)p)->aField + 100); }`. You can see what the requirements are, as the possible pitfalls

Comment: "Without thinking too hard about why you'd want to do this" I'm going to think about it, because I'm sure there's a better way of doing whatever you are *actually* trying to do. Either way, `Unsafe.AsPointer(ref this)` should work in a struct method, although it's obviously "unsafe" and subject to the pointer being moved.

Comment: @Charlieface you can't pass `this` as a `ref` parameter.

Comment: @Jimi as I understand it, once you return from the `fixed` scope, the thing you have the pointer to is no longer fixed, and given the way that tasks are suspended and resumed there's a reasonable chance that the pointed-to value could have been moved, at which point you get dangly pointers. I suspect this is all intertwined with why you aren't allowed `in`, `out` or `ref` in `async` methods (and why in rust `Pin` is required and a bit of a pain to work with).

Comment: You can if it's a struct, and the result is reflected back to the original value https://dotnetfiddle.net/bepNrG, although I've noticed that because `async` methods make a copy of `this`, the result is not reflected in the original. Also `async Something.ElseAsync` method being called can't have a `ref` parameter anyway. I still think you should explain better what you are *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: That's why I've removed the `async` keyword from the methods that return `Task` / `Task<T>`. The call to `Something.ElseAsync()` is then done inside the `unsafe { fixed  { } }` blocks -- As mentioned, it's not clear what you want to achieve here. As also mentioned, a `ref struct` is probably best suited. It's guaranteed that it does not move outside the stack

Comment: @Jimi If you remove `async` then you can use normal `ref` anyway. No need for messing with `unsafe`.

Comment: @Charlieface I certainly agree with that